# Google OAuth2-Flow with Python: problems with step2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have a problem with the oauth2-Authorization in google, especially with the step 2: exchange of code into an access token. Here is my code:

```
import httplib2   
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.discovery import build
import simplejson as json
import cgi
...
#initiating the flow
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='<client_id>',
                       client_secret='<client_secret>',
                       scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                       redirect_uri='<url_to_this_script')

#initiating storing
storage = Storage('credentials_store.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

#checks, if there is a code already transmitted
if form.has_key("code"):
        code = form["code"].value
        #step 2: if so, then try to get credentials with the code
        #HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
        storage.put(credentials)

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        #step 1: get the code
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        print "Location:%s" % auth_uri
        print # to end the CGI response headers.
```

So I try to explain:

1. If there is no "code" in the parameters, when calling the script, the first if-then-else-check will be passed and the program starts with step 1. This part is fine. The user will be redirected to a page where he can authorisize the script.
2. The script will be called again after authorisation, but this time with the "code" in the parameter. As described in the google developers reference I try to get credentials with this command

   credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

Until this step it works fine but then it stops with the error message:

```
oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: invalid_request
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

P.S.: The application needs access just to my own documents in google drive, if this is interesting to you.

Edit:
Here is the complete error message:

```
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167] No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.client"
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]   File "/is/htdocs/wp1108372_VJATWIO8DR/www/cgi-bin/ref_ScopeGetter2.py", line 84, in [module]
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]     http = auth_http("Axel","Drive")
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]   File "/is/htdocs/wp1108372_VJATWIO8DR/www/cgi-bin/ref_ScopeGetter2.py", line 76, in __init__
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]     self.auth_http = self.get_auth_http(user,scope)
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]   File "/is/htdocs/wp1108372_VJATWIO8DR/www/cgi-bin/ref_ScopeGetter2.py", line 51, in get_auth_http
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]     credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]   File "/is/htdocs/wp1108372_VJATWIO8DR/www/cgi-bin/oauth2client/client.py", line 910, in step2_exchange
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167]     raise FlowExchangeError(error_msg)
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167] oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: invalid_request
[Thu Jul 03 07:14:07 2014] [error] [client 31.19.230.167] Premature end of script headers: ref_ScopeGetter2.py
```

Comment: Have you tested with `redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'` ?

Comment: Could you show the whole request and response of this error?

Comment: for the response see the edited question. The request is just the command-line.